# Sharing your standard text and multiple links on Facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

How make up can share a standard text using Facebook SDK (either version 3.5 and the latest version of SDK) plus 3 or more links. 
Something for example:

*Text text text text, text link, link, link...*

In the latest version of the SDK I saw this:

```
ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
        .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://developers.facebook.com"))
        .build();
```

But I do not know if I can share more than one link and another text in the format mentioned ...
And I do not mind the version 3.5 of the SDK have this possibility...

Comment: You are not allowed to specify the message for the user – they have to type it in themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android), this kind of need is not possible.